# How to generate machine code with llvm

Tags: c++, llvm, machine-code

I'm currently working on a compiler project using llvm. I have followed various tutorials to the point where I have a parser to create a syntax tree and then the tree is converted into an llvm Module using the provided IRBuilder.

My goal is to create an executable, and I am confused as what to do next. All the tutorials I've found just create the llvm module and print out the assembly using Module.dump(). Additionally, the only documentation I can find is for llvm developers, and not end users of the project.

If I want to generate machine code, what are the next steps? The llvm-mc project looks like it may do what I want, but I can't find any sort of documentation on it.

Perhaps I'm expecting llvm to do something that it doesn't. My expectation is that I can build a Module, then there would be an API that I can call with the Module and a target triple and an object file will be produced. I have found documentation and examples on producing a JIT, and I am not interested in that. I am looking for how to produce compiled binaries.

I am working on OS X, if that has any impact.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `llc -filetype=obj` to emit a linkable object file from your IR. You can look at the code of `llc` to see the LLVM API calls it makes to emit such code. At least for Mac OS X and Linux, the objects emitted in such a manner should be pretty good (i.e. this is not a "alpha quality" option by now).

LLVM does not contain a linker (yet!), however. So to actually link this object file into some executable or shared library, you will need to use the system linker. Note that even if you have an executable consisting of a single object file, the latter has to be linked anyway. Developers in the LLVM community are working on a real linker for LLVM, called `lld`. You can visit [its page](http://lld.llvm.org/) or search the mailing list archives to follow its progress.

Comment: Do you think you could update this answer?

Comment: @Jeppe: unfortunately it's been years since I worked with LLVM. Happy to review edits

Answer (score 18):

As you can read on [the llc guide](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llc.html), it is indeed intended to just generate the assembly, and then "The assembly language output can then be passed through a native assembler and linker to generate a native executable" - e.g. the gnu assembler (`as`) and linker (`ld`).

So the main answer here is to **use native tools for assembling and linking**.

However, there's experimental support for generating the native object directly from an IR file, via `llc`:

```
-filetype      - Choose a file type (not all types are supported by all targets):
    =asm         -   Emit an assembly ('.s') file
    =obj         -   Emit a native object ('.o') file [experimental]
```

Or you can use `llvm-mc` to assemble it from the `.s` file:

```
-filetype      - Choose an output file type:
    =asm         -   Emit an assembly ('.s') file
    =null        -   Don't emit anything (for timing purposes)
    =obj         -   Emit a native object ('.o') file
```

I don't know about linkers, though.

In addition, I recommend checking out the `tools/bugpoint/ToolRunner.h` file, which exposes a wrapper combining `llc` and the platform's native C toolchain for generating machine code. From its header comment:

> This file exposes an abstraction around a platform C compiler, used to compile C and assembly code.

Answer (score 8):

Check out these functions in `llvm-c/TargetMachine.h`:

```
/** Emits an asm or object file for the given module to the filename. This
  wraps several c++ only classes (among them a file stream). Returns any
  error in ErrorMessage. Use LLVMDisposeMessage to dispose the message. */
LLVMBool LLVMTargetMachineEmitToFile(LLVMTargetMachineRef T, LLVMModuleRef M,
  char *Filename, LLVMCodeGenFileType codegen, char **ErrorMessage);

/** Compile the LLVM IR stored in \p M and store the result in \p OutMemBuf. */
LLVMBool LLVMTargetMachineEmitToMemoryBuffer(LLVMTargetMachineRef T, LLVMModuleRef M,
  LLVMCodeGenFileType codegen, char** ErrorMessage, LLVMMemoryBufferRef *OutMemBuf);
```

Answer (score 1):

To run the example `BrainF` program, compile it and run:

```
echo ,. > test.bf
./BrainF test.bf -o test.bc
llc -filetype=obj test.bc
gcc test.o -o a.out
./a.out
```

then type a single letter and press Enter. It should echo that letter back to you. (That's what `,.` does.)

The above was tested with LLVM version 3.5.0.