# generate machine code directly via LLVM API

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api

With the following code, I can generate an *LLVM bitcode file* from a module:

```
llvm::Module * module;

// fill module with code
module = ...;

std::error_code ec;
llvm::raw_fd_ostream out("anonymous.bc", ec, llvm::sys::fs::F_None);

llvm::WriteBitcodeToFile(module, out);
```

I can then use that bitcode file to generate an executable machine code file, e.g.:

```
clang -o anonymous anonymous.bc
```

Alternatively:

```
llc anonymous.bc
gcc -o anonymous anonymous.s
```

---

My question now is: Can I generate the machine code directly in C++ with the LLVM API without first needing to write the bitcode file?

I am looking for either **a code example** or at least some starting points in the LLVM API, e.g. which classes to use, nudging me in the right direction might even be enough.

Comment: I didn't get it. You want a shell script that uses LLVM tools to generate machine code without intermediate files, or you want to do it via LLVM API?

Comment: I admit, the wording of the question was ambiguous. Edited to clarify: I want to do it via the LLVM API.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a give-me-the-codez website. I'm afraid that, although I can answer your question with ease, I certainly won't. Do your own job.

Comment: Thanks, @Puppy, you are so very helpful, why are you even using stackoverflow?

Comment: There are many reasons, but to write code for lazy people to copy and paste is not one of them.

Comment: Copy and paste where from? I've searched and didn't find anything. Don't you at least care to put me on to something?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33900895/432

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [llc tool source](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/llvm/trunk/tools/llc/llc.cpp?view=markup), spcifically `compileModule()` function. In short, it creates `Target`, sets some options for it via `TargetOptions`, then uses it to `addPassesToEmitFile()` and finally asks `PassManager` to perform all planned tasks.

Comment: Thanks, that really helped. As far as I can see, this way I can output a "*.o" or "*.obj" native object file, but there is no linking. Can linking be done directly via LLVM yet, or is that still in the works?

Comment: There is lld project, which performs linking and it is quite usable on some arches (OSX and Linux). But recently i saw a discussion on the mailing list regarding its architecture not allowing using it as library. It has been decided that lld should provide such API, but i suppose it's still a work-in-progress, yes.

Answer (score 6):

I was also looking for the code for this, and @arrowd's suggestion worked.

To save the trouble for the next person, this is what I came up with.

Given a Module, it generates assembly code on stdout for your native target:

```
void printASM(Module *M) {
    InitializeNativeTarget();
    InitializeNativeTargetAsmPrinter();

    auto TargetTriple = sys::getDefaultTargetTriple();
    M->setTargetTriple(TargetTriple);

    std::string Error;
    const Target *target = TargetRegistry::lookupTarget(TargetTriple, Error);
    auto cpu = sys::getHostCPUName();
    SubtargetFeatures Features;
    StringMap<bool> HostFeatures;
    if (sys::getHostCPUFeatures(HostFeatures))
        for (auto &F : HostFeatures)
            Features.AddFeature(F.first(), F.second);
    auto features = Features.getString();

    TargetOptions Options;
    std::unique_ptr<TargetMachine> TM{
            target->createTargetMachine(
                    TargetTriple, cpu, features, Options,
                    Reloc::PIC_, None, CodeGenOpt::None)
    };

    legacy::PassManager PM;
    M->setDataLayout(TM->createDataLayout());
    TM->addPassesToEmitFile(PM, (raw_pwrite_stream &) outs(), (raw_pwrite_stream *) (&outs()),
                            TargetMachine::CodeGenFileType::CGFT_AssemblyFile, true, nullptr);
    PM.run(*M);
}
```

If anyone knows a shorter way to write this code, feel free to correct me!